# Unable to load /home SSD drive - Mounted /boot/eft A start job is running for dev/sdb1

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, ssd, fstab

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 server. Everything worked until I decided to move my SSD drive to a 3.5 adapter to fit with the older hard drive in there.

I installed XFCE previously and was able to login using that interface. However, it will not log me in on either user account. The drive appears (sdc1) is lsblk.

```
    NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    loop0                       7:0    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
    loop1                       7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
    loop2                       7:2    0  70.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16922
    loop3                       7:3    0  71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
    loop4                       7:4    0  30.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
    loop5                       7:5    0    31M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9607
    sda                         8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
    ├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
    ├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
    └─sda3                      8:3    0   1.8T  0 part
      └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
    sdb                         8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
    sdc                         8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk
    └─sdc1                      8:33   0 232.9G  0 part
    sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I am able to access via Putty with either login. I am glad I set this up.

I get a message at bootup

```
   mounted /boot/eft A start job is running for /dec/sdb1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After I realized the sdb1 is not where the /home files are located and is in fact a spare drive that is unformatted. My guess was to change the fstab file.

```
  nano -e /etc/fstab
```

This showed /dev/sdb1 was the /home ext4 default. I simply changed to /dev/sdc1 and everything is working as it should again.

Comment: it is better to use UUID for mounting.  `sudo lsblk -f`